# is string formatter `% + tuple` deprecated?

Tags: python, format

There are two ways of doing string formatting in python:

- Using the `%` followed by a tuple:

  ```
  '%s %s' % ('one', 'two')
  ```
- Using `format`:

  ```
  '{} {}'.format('one', 'two')
  ```

The [PyFormat webpage](https://pyformat.info/) has a very nice list of options for formatting.
However I noticed that they call the `% + tuple` method "OLD" (instead of classic or another non-negative name)

My question is simple: Is the "old" method deprecated and therefore we should use `format`, or both methods are OK to use?

It looks like `format` is more powerful and can do things that the "old" method can't.

Comment: Old, *relatively* (the "new" format style adds some new features), not deprecated

Comment: No, it is not deprecated. And now there are three ways of doing formatting; you missed `f` strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without speaking about performance, because in python 3 `%` *could* be deleted, `format` is preferred.

[Old string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting):

> Since str.format() is quite new, a lot of Python code still uses the %
>   operator. However, because this old style of formatting will
>   eventually be removed from the language, str.format() should generally
>   be used.

Comment: Ok, so `%` is kept for compatibility but new code should better use `format`, thanks

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki That's it.